# how to package a standalone xulrunner application

Tags: xul, xulrunner

I was wondering what I need to do to create an executable (.exe) file that will run my XUL application?

I'm trying to create an application using Mozilla's XUL format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. Compress your application folder tree using WinZip.
2. Rename the .zip file to have a .xpi extension. (i.e., myApp.xpi).
3. Assuming you have xulrunner in your PATH, execute: xulrunner --install-app myApp.xpi.

On Windows, this installs your app to

```
c:\Program Files\<Vendor>\<Application Name>\<Application Name>.exe
```

Where  and  match exactly with what is in your application.ini file.

On Linux, the process is similar. On OS X, though, things are [quite a bit different](http://www.kenpardue.com/2008/04/29/creating-a-xulrunner-19-app-on-os-x/). I haven't completed mastered the OS X process yet.

See also [Deploying XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner/Deploying_XULRunner_1.8).

Comment: I've been working more with xulrunner applications so I understand them better to know what your talking about :P
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry it's taken me so long to reply! I've finaly learned how to build a XUL applicaton. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Ready to use build scripts for packaging a minimal xulrunner application are available [here](https://github.com/neam/webapp-xul-wrapper).

Comment: --install-app option was recently replaced with the script install_app.py https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747597

Answer (score 1):

It is too bad that xulrunner can not run a zipped .xpi or .xulapp directly, but it is possible to package most of your .js, .xul, .css and .png files into a jar and wrap everything up with a private copy of xulrunner, without having to run --install-app

These are the steps I went through to package our XUL application.

The first step is to put all your files (except *application.ini*, *chrome.manifest*, and *prefs.js*) into a .jar file like this (all of this was carried out under Windows, make appropriate adjustments for Linux and OSX)

```
zip -r d:\download\space\akenispace.jar * -i *.js *.css *.png *.xul *.dtd
```

Then in d:\download\space, layout your files as follows:

```
D:\download\space\akenispace.jar
D:\download\space\application.ini
D:\download\space\chrome.manifest
D:\download\space\defaults
D:\download\space\defaults\preferences
D:\download\space\defaults\preferences\prefs.js
```

The content of the files are as follows. All three files need to be adjusted to reflect your own application.

***application.ini***

```
[App]
Vendor=Akeni.Technologies
Name=Akeni.Space
Version=1.2.3
BuildID=20150125
Copyright=Copyright (c) 2015
ID=space@akeni.com

[Gecko]
MinVersion=1.8
MaxVersion=35
```

***chrome.manifest***

```
content     akenispace             jar:akenispace.jar!/chrome/content/
skin        akenispace    default  jar:akenispace.jar!/chrome/skin/
locale      akenispace    en-US    jar:akenispace.jar!/chrome/locale/en-US/
resource    akenispace             jar:akenispace.jar!/chrome/resource/
```

***prefs.js***

```
pref("toolkit.defaultChromeURI", "chrome://akenispace/content/space.xul");
```

Now you can put these files into your .wxs for WiX and produce a MSI file for Wndows. 
Of course you need to include all the files for XULRunner as well.