# Single-file app with xulrunner - possible?

Tags: linux, firefox, xul, xulrunner

I have tried to mess with `xulrunner` before, and now I'm trying once again :)

The "real" tutorial ([Getting started with XULRunner - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Getting_started_with_XULRunner#Step_7%3a_Create_some_XUL)) does, in fact, show that one is supposed to have `application.ini` and other files (*possibly zipped as .xpi, which then requires `--install-app ...`*), and then the call should be like:

```
xulrunner `pwd`/application.ini
```

... however, I'd like an easier way to start up - and hence, my hope for single-file XUL application approach :) (*A good note here is that one also cannot use the zipped .xpi as an argument to `xulrunner`, see [XULRunner question - DonationCoder.com](https://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=15314.0;prev_next=next)*)

The thing is, I am almost 100% certain that at some point in the past, I have used a simple single-file XUL application, as in (pseudocode):

```
xulrunner my-xul-app.extension
```

... but I cannot remember how it went :) So, was that possible with `xulrunner`, or only with `firefox`?

As far as I can remember, I used something like a 'my-xul-app.xul' file (*as the single-file application*), which would specify only, say, a window with a single button (*that couldn't really do anything due to lack of javascript*) - and I'd like to repeat the same thing now, to refresh my memory (*unless I confused something from back then :)*)

First of all, I found [HOWTO: Getting Started with Linux Standalone Apps using XUL - Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=333862) (2007), and I modified the `example.xul` file used there as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<window
id = "myapp"
title = "SQLite Example"
height = "420"
minHeight = "420"
width = "640"
minWidth = "640"
screenX = "10"
screenY = "10"
sizemode = "normal"
xmlns = "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" >
<spacer style = "height: 4px; cursor: default;" />
</window>
```

and I'm trying to "run" this as recommended in link, with:

```
firefox -no-remote -chrome file:$PWD/example.xul
```

... and what happens is that Firefox opens, with window size being like 1x1 pixels; if you can find the handle, you can stretch the window, and read:

> Remote XUL
>   This page uses an unsupported technology that is no longer available by default in Firefox.

Ouch :( Answers to this (*like [How do I fix the Remote XUL error I get when using Firefox 4.x and the Webmail Advanced Interface?](http://support.aiso.net/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=260)*) seem to be related to *actual remote* xul (and recommend a plugin to handle that); but what I want is simply to run a file *locally*?! Where did the "remote" part come from?

Also, seeing the firefox switch '`-app`' ([Using Firefox 3 as a XUL runtime environment](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2007/08/using-firefox-3-as-a-xul-runtime-environment.ars)); although it refers to an `application.ini`, I tried this:

```
firefox -no-remote -app $PWD/example.xul
```

... and Firefox just started as usual.

Btw, I cannot see neither `-app` nor `-chrome` command line options in `firefox --help` ;)

But actually, I do not really want to use `firefox` as an engine - just the `xulrunner`; and I tried the Firefox approach because I thought it is more-less the same as `xulrunner`; turns out it isn't (even if you use `application.ini`: [Why does 'firefox -App application.ini' and 'xulrunner application.ini' behave differentely? | Firefox Support Forum](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/755812)):

In any case, if I run just `xulrunner` (as I wanted to), I get:

```
$ xulrunner example.xul 
Error: App:Name not specified in application.ini
```

So, I can see everything points to "single source file" app not being possible with `xulrunner` - but I just wanted to make sure (in case I missed some obscure tutorial :) ). And if it isn't - does anyone remember if it was possible at a previous point in time?

PS:

```
$ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 7.0.1
$ xulrunner --version
Mozilla XULRunner 2.0 - 20110402003021
$ uname -r
2.6.38-11-generic
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 11.04 \n \l
```

Comment: That is..a wall of text. You should make you questions clear.

Comment: Thanks for the note, @Nacereddine - I'm aware it's a wall, but I just wanted to note all the possible combos I tried; so at least not to go through it again, should I find myself in the same situation again. Cheers!

Comment: Firefox (Preinstalled on Linux most of the time) is able to run xulrunner apps according to this, so it should be quite easy to make a script to run it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XULRunner_tips#Using_Firefox_3_to_run_XULRunner_applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you could ever create single-file XULRunner applications. The `-chrome <...>` parameter probably used to work, I guess the "Remote XUL" error comes from the fact that the URL is file://, not chrome://.

You could use something like the [Live XUL Editor in the Developer Assistant](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/extension-developer/) (formerly Extension Developer's extension) to test XUL quickly.

The general idea I hear these days is that you should write HTML5 instead, whenever you can, since it is more actively developed, more well-known technology with less incompatible changes and better tooling...

Comment: Thanks for confirming that @Nickolay... although I was expecting it, its a shame the single-file approach isn't possible :) Also +1 for the URL note - and the Live XUL Editor link (never heard about it before)... Thanks again - cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer I wrote for another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325881/how-to-package-a-standalone-xulrunner-application), reproduced here because it may help someone who want to know how to package their XUL application.

It is too bad that xulrunner can not run a zipped .xpi or .xulapp directly, but it is possible to package most of your .js, .xul, .css and .png files into a jar and wrap everything up with a private copy of xulrunner, without having to run --install-app

These are the steps I went through to package our XUL application.

The first step is to put all your files (except *application.ini*, *chrome.manifest*, and *prefs.js*) into a .jar file like this (all of this was carried out under Windows, make appropriate adjustments for Linux and OSX)

```
zip -r d:\download\space\akenispace.jar * -i *.js *.css *.png *.xul *.dtd
```

Then in d:\download\space, layout your files as follows:

```
D:\download\space\akenispace.jar
D:\download\space\application.ini
D:\download\space\chrome.manifest
D:\download\space\defaults
D:\download\space\defaults\preferences
D:\download\space\defaults\preferences\prefs.js
```

The content of the files are as follows

***application.ini***

```
[App]
Vendor=Akeni.Technologies
Name=Akeni.Space
Version=1.2.3
BuildID=20150125
Copyright=Copyright (c) 2015
ID=space@akeni.com

[Gecko]
MinVersion=1.8
MaxVersion=35
```

***chrome.manifest***

```
content     akenispace             jar:akenispace.jar!/chrome/content/
skin        akenispace    default  jar:akenispace.jar!/chrome/skin/
locale      akenispace    en-US    jar:akenispace.jar!/chrome/locale/en-US/
resource    akenispace             jar:akenispace.jar!/chrome/resource/
```

***prefs.js***

```
pref("toolkit.defaultChromeURI", "chrome://akenispace/content/space.xul");
```

Now you can put these files into your .wxs for WiX and produce an MSI file for Wndows.

Of course you need to include all the files for XULRunner as well.